# Multiple Monitors Detect Add Remove Laptop Auto Change Nvidia X Server Settings

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

**Physical Setup;**
4 monitors, 1 laptop, 1 hdmi switch box, 1 graphics card used for all 4 displays.

Monitors listed in nvidia x server settings as;
CRT-0, DFP-1, DFP-3, DFP-4.

**Short description of problem;**
Start linux.
If needed goto nvidia x server settings and arrange 4 monitor screens.
Save configuration.
Laptop is displayed on laptop's own built in monitor.

Use hdmi switch box, laptop is now displayed on 'main' [DFP-1] monitor.
3 remaining monitors change to 'alternative' nvidia x settings 'A'.

Use hdmi switch box, laptop is now displayed on laptop's own built in monitor.
4 monitors change to 'alternative' nvidia x settings 'B'.

**The good bit;**
Boot or reboot linux with laptop display on it's own built in monitor.
Everything is layed out nicely. 
Specifically the task bar is shown on 'main' [DFP-1] monitor and monitor [DFP-3] has orientation as rotate left.
Settings are not lost on reboot.

**Long description of the problem;**
Use hdmi switch box.
1. DFP-1 is no longer connected to linux machine.
2. DFP-1 now shows what was displayed on laptop's own built in monitor.
3. CRT-0 now has task bar.
4. CRT-0 now shows what was being displayed on DFP-1.
5. DFP-3 orientation is now normal, orientation is no longer rotated left.
6. DFP-3 now shows what was being displayed on DFP-3.
7. DFP-3 additionally shows what was being displayed on DFP-1 on top.
8. DFP-4 remains unchanged.

Notes.
7. what i mean here is say i had chrome web browser open on DFP-1 and skype on DFP-3.
after using the switch box, skype would still be shown on DFP-3 but over the top would be the chrome web browser.

**Wished for / Wanted / Desired behaviour ?**
linux to use 2 nvidia x server settings.
One setting for when DFP-1 is present and another for when it is not present.

Is there a way to;
A. detect DFP-1 state, connected, disconnected, reconnected ? 
B. have 2 or more nvidia x server settings configuration files ?
C. change between nvidia x server settings configuration files 'on the fly' ?

Hopefully I have outlined the problem I am experiencing adequately, with enough information, that someone, with the ability to provide a solution, can understand it.

In other words,
Can anyone who can help me, please ?

*Side note

What is with the need to use html to correctly format a question ?

Is it some sort of test ?

Totally unnecessary, Elitist, off putting behaviour.*